# How do I not require authorization for index?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to make the homepage of my website accessible without authorization, however, Spring keeps asking for a login when I access it.

I configured it in my SecurityConfig to allow this but it is still not working.

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import security.MyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
}
```

I also have an Initializer class I added to see if it would fix things but I think it is unneeded in spring-boot.

Initializer

```
package com.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I am able to send POSTs to /login without authentication and when I disable csrf protection in the config it picks that up so I do not think it is a problem with Spring not finding the configuration.

Here are the logs from Spring

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.4.RELEASE)

2017-07-19 03:09:22.347  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] com.mp.DemoApplication                   : Starting DemoApplication on Meade with PID 7832 (C:\Users\markp\git\Abbraa\target\classes started by markp in C:\Users\markp\git\Abbraa)
2017-07-19 03:09:22.348  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] com.mp.DemoApplication                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-19 03:09:22.771  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@39cff043: startup date [Wed Jul 19 03:09:22 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-19 03:09:24.027  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientContextConfiguration] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=session; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration; factoryMethodName=oauth2ClientContext; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration.class]]
2017-07-19 03:09:24.394  WARN 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'beanNamePlaceholderRegistryPostProcessor' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2017-07-19 03:09:24.764  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Post-processing PropertySource instances
2017-07-19 03:09:24.792  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.j.c.StringEncryptorConfiguration     : String Encryptor custom Bean not found with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'. Initializing String Encryptor based on properties with name 'jasyptStringEncryptor'
2017-07-19 03:09:24.801  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource commandLineArgs [org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource] to EncryptableEnumerablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.801  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletConfigInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.802  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource servletContextInitParams [org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource$StubPropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.802  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemProperties [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.802  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource systemEnvironment [org.springframework.core.env.SystemEnvironmentPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.803  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource random [org.springframework.boot.context.config.RandomValuePropertySource] to EncryptablePropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.803  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties] [org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:24.803  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] eEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor : Converting PropertySource refresh [org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource] to EncryptableMapPropertySourceWrapper
2017-07-19 03:09:25.629  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-19 03:09:25.644  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-07-19 03:09:25.645  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
2017-07-19 03:09:25.900  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-19 03:09:25.900  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3133 ms
2017-07-19 03:09:26.249  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.250  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.250  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.251  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'OAuth2ClientContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.251  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.253  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.253  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-07-19 03:09:26.254  INFO 7832 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2017-07-19 03:09:27.168  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-19 03:09:27.191  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-07-19 03:09:27.281  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-07-19 03:09:27.283  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-07-19 03:09:27.286  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-07-19 03:09:27.341  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-07-19 03:09:27.489  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-07-19 03:09:27.840  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-07-19 03:09:27.848  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-07-19 03:09:27.887  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-19 03:09:28.186  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] b.a.s.AuthenticationManagerConfiguration : 

Using default security password: b93e6b62-c3c6-41c6-b1fb-aff865c47624

2017-07-19 03:09:28.513  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-07-19 03:09:28.514  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2017-07-19 03:09:28.515  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-19 03:09:28.516  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-19 03:09:28.517  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String)
2017-07-19 03:09:28.517  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-19 03:09:28.518  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-07-19 03:09:29.074  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] a.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration : Initialized OAuth2 Client

security.oauth2.client.clientId = 8f83ba6f-ddd0-4584-989e-8bf15d9ca800
security.oauth2.client.secret = 90f22f41-57ea-4a35-b4aa-f2e2c228b9c5


2017-07-19 03:09:29.546  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@39cff043: startup date [Wed Jul 19 03:09:22 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-19 03:09:29.655  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mp.MainController.index()
2017-07-19 03:09:29.656  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/logon],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.mp.MainController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2017-07-19 03:09:29.660  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-07-19 03:09:29.661  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-07-19 03:09:29.738  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-19 03:09:29.738  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-19 03:09:29.816  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-19 03:09:30.844  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2017-07-19 03:09:30.978  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/oauth/token'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key'], Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@147facd0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@57681424, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@60769ed5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7abdb07c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@69b1535d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6fc31f04, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1388aafd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@77b72eb9, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@26bc4252, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@b0ad272, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6190b047]
2017-07-19 03:09:30.995  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4464b064, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@57affbac, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@29e75695, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7f423605, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5798d0da, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@24ff986, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@110f44a4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6fb5646d, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2079db43, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@245e3d72, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@e6e5393]
2017-07-19 03:09:31.017  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@26d80f5b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@243b400b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@dbb1e82, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@35f7f5a9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4b32c004, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@a677b9e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5ffd3b5e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@22a0c587, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@8d5dbd, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6bd8b55f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1b162e0f]
2017-07-19 03:09:31.236  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-07-19 03:09:31.313  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-07-19 03:09:31.431  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-19 03:09:31.439  INFO 7832 --- [  restartedMain] com.mp.DemoApplication                   : Started DemoApplication in 9.556 seconds (JVM running for 10.373)
2017-07-19 03:09:42.498  INFO 7832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-07-19 03:09:42.498  INFO 7832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-07-19 03:09:42.540  INFO 7832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 41 ms
```

I was wondering if there is something wrong with the way I am doing my SecurityConfig.configure method or if there is another reason why it is not allowing access.

Comment: I believe it is the OAuth2ClientContextFilter how did you configure the oauth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that my projects weren't structured correctly as my main app was in a different package than some of my configs. I was able to fix the problem by moving my main application into a root package. I looked at the Spring styling guide and found that the Autoconfig and Component scan need to have all the other files in a sub package of the main app to work correctly.

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html